# How to include files from a Git repo?

Tags: databricks, databricks-asset-bundle

I'm trying to build a Databricks asset bundle from files - notebooks, jobs, and pipelines - stored in a Git repo.

I found this page [Databricks asset bundle configurations](https://docs.databricks.com/en/dev-tools/bundles/settings.html#databricks-asset-bundle-configurations). It mentions Git but the references are  under the *bundle* mapping. To me, this indicates the bundle can be found at the Git url and not useful when initially building the bundle.

I'd expect to see Git options under the *include* mapping. This process is new to me so any examples or documentation that show how to build a bundle from files in a repo would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

[asset bundle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNGWr.png)

[job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAKqI.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).